# How can I manually advance a timeline in GameMaker?

Tags: game-maker

I have a timeline from 0 to 300 frames divided into maybe 20 different steps.

When I certain condition is met, I want to jump to the next step of that timeline. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need fully automatical processing, then you can put all the moments to array and then check `timeline_position` with these values.

A small example. You have timeline with moments 0, 100, 500, and 1000.
In `Create` event define the array:

```
// store timeline moments to the array
moments[0] = 0;
moments[1] = 100;
moments[2] = 500;
moments[3] = 1000;

// start timeline
timeline_index = timeline0;
timeline_position = 0;
timeline_running = true;
```

And how you can jump:

```
for (var i=0; i<array_length_1d(moments); i++)
{
    var pos = moments[i];
    if timeline_position > pos continue;

    show_message("current position: " + string(timeline_position) + "#next position: " + string(pos));
    timeline_position = pos;
    break;
}
```

In case when you need to do it fully automatically, then you need to do same way, but you need create the timeline yourself using `timeline_moment_add_script` function.